# Converting Modelica Library package from Dymola to Open Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

There is an open source Modelica Library package that I want to use in Open Modelica/OMEdit
The package was originally developed in Dymola, and is available here:
https://greenhouses-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

When I open the library in OMEdit and check the "Greenhouse" Example model it provides this error message, which I believe is telling me that the dymola library is not available.

`[1] 15:04:18 Scripting Notification You can install the requested package using one of the commands: installPackage(DymolaCommands, "master", exactMatch=true) installPackage(DymolaCommands, "1.1", exactMatch=false) installPackage(DymolaCommands, "1.1", exactMatch=false).`
`
Does anyone have info on how to convert a library that was originally developed in dymola to be suitable for Open Modelica. The OpenModelica documentation talks about porting, but I'm not sure how to systematically remove and replace any of the references to DymolaCommands.

Please note - engineer, attempting to use this code to shortcut a piece of work. Steep learning curve....

Tried deleting the text DymolaCommands(version="1.1"),  just get a lot more error strings when checking the models,

Tried searching for dymola commands library online - no package available

Attempted to "Load External model" in OM edit but no luck.

Comment: The problem seems to be with a redeclaration of some Media/Fluid component. I will add this library to our testing to find out all the issues in the library and see if we can fix them (either in the library or in the OpenModelica code). The library will appear here in a couple of hours: https://libraries.openmodelica.org/branches/overview.html
I will come back here with some new comments when things evolve.

Comment: You can now try to get the library I forked: https://github.com/adrpo/Greenhouses-Library and use that to simulate the examples. I could get it to simulate and also updated it to MSL 4.0.0

Answer (score 4):

Ok. I had to fork the library to change some things in it:

- fix the cardinality handling
- fix the way specificEnthalpy_pT and specificEnthalpy_pTX was handled
- the DymolaCommands library was not even used, I removed the dependency
- I updated the library to be able to use MSL to 4.0.0

With my changes the models compile but simulation has issues at initialization, I will check those later.

I then repointed the Greenhouse library in OpenModelica to my fork:
https://github.com/adrpo/Greenhouses-Library
so if you update it from OpenModelica you will get the new version with my changes.

We will also get automatic testing for it from now on here:
https://libraries.openmodelica.org/branches/master/Greenhouses/Greenhouses.html

I will make a PR with my changes to the original library and if they accept my PR we can switch the OpenModelica library index one back to it.

Comment: As for proposed change: When changing the cardinality-check to be for the connector elements it would make sense to also set individual unconnected elements to zero, instead of setting all to zero iff none are connected. I couldn't see why specificEnthalphy_pTX should be used instead of specificEnthalphy_pT - is it needed or just for consistency?

Comment: I have changed the cardinality handling to do that by moving the check inside the for loop. The problem with using specificEnthalphy_pT is that it calls specificEnthalphy_pTX with fill(0, 0) as last argument but the type of the function expects fill(0, 1) because it defaults to reference_X. This seems to be a bug in Media, I will see if I can open a PR to fix it.

Comment: I don't see that just because is reference_X we can conclude that argument should be fill(0,1) instead of fill(0,0). As far as I can see the X-argument is ignored in single-species Media, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the spec. If you have an input array with no dimensions specified that has a binding, do you apply the dimension of that binding to the type of the function or not before checking the compatibility with given arguments? Yes, the input is not used but that's not reason enough to ignore a typing error.

Comment: I gave it another look and - as usual - it seems you are right and this looks like a bug in OM. I can't reproduce the error I got with a simpler example so I guess something goes wrong with typing if redeclare + package constants are involved.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/11158

Comment: It seems there is a bit of an issue in Media as a redeclare changes the array dimension from : to nX.

Answer (score 0):

DymolaCommand is a library distributed with Dymola that contains a lot of functions pointing to external c-functions to ease the use of models etc. It seems that the library you are using is using functions from this package.
Have you tried to use the models with a Dymola demo version? you could also ask for a test license.
The only other solution would be to find out which functions are used from the DymolaCommands and to replace the functions with your own code.

Comment: Thanks Imke. The model is too large to load into the demo version of dymola. But I will see if I can get access to a test license.   Otherwise I guess I will be doing it the hard way and seeing if I can mine out the functions that are from Dymola Command.  Thanks for the help!